# How to prevent escaping a blade syntax?

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to use the helper to set an e-mail address:

```
Email: contact@{{ request()->getHost() }}
```

But apparently, `@` before `{{` is used to escape Blade instructions!

How can we prevent this escaping functionality?

Comment: Whats about it `Email: {{ 'contact@'. $request()->getHost() }}` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `@` as a string:

```
Email: contact{{ '@'. $request()->getHost() }}
```